# Multiplicative orders Vs order of a multiplicative group

Tags: math, cryptography, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, number-theory

How to demonstrate that all multiplicative orders divide the order (size) of the multiplicative group F of F13.
.

Comment: please move this purely math question to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: And please demonstrate that you have already searched for a solution by posting your ideas, even if they did not lead to the solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mathematical proof and better asked at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: See [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show that the cyclic group `<x>` generated by an element x is a subgroup of IF* and that "`u~v iff u^(-1)*v in <x>`" is an equivalence relation that divides the multiplicative group into equivalence classes of equal size.

So that you get

```
[size of IF*] 
     = [size of <x>] * [number of equivalence classes]
```

which means that the order of x = `[size of <x>]` is a divisor of the number of invertible elements, i.e., the size of the multiplicative group of `IF`

See also the little theorem of Fermat.

Answer (score 1):

Since the group is abelian, the simplest thing is to use that multiplication by any element is a bijection. Let F = {g1, g2, g3, ..., gn} and let h be an arbitrary element. Then also F = {h*g1, h*g2, ..., h*gn}. Hence multiplying all elements together we get g1 * g2 * g3 * ... * gn = h*g1 * h*g2 * ... * h*gn. But the latter equals h^n * g1 * g2 * ... * gn. Now use the cancellation law to conclude that h^n = 1 from which the result follows.